# How to convert dicom, mhd, or nhdr to Openvdb?

Tags: image-processing

I'd like to make a high quality volume rendering of an MRI scan in Maya with the Arnold Renderer. Preferably with a color map (lookup table) preapplied though I could go without. Unfortunately I can only import openvdbs into maya for volumes. I'm looking for some software that will convert dicom, mhd, nhdr, or even a series of pngs or jpgs to openvdb so I can import it into Maya. I can't seem to find anything that will do this. I thought maybe Houdini could but couldn't figure it out. Is my only option using the openvdb api and doing it myself?

Comment: @user1118321 I didn't ask for a recommendation? I asked how to convert mri data to openvdb

Comment: You literally asked, "I'm looking for some software that will convert..." That's asking for a recommendation of software that will do the conversion. How is it not?

Comment: @user1118321 A recommendation is asking for a best course of action. I didn't ask for a "best" (opinionated/subjective) course of action. I simply asked for A course of action. The fact is this is most likely not possible with any software.

Comment: A course of action is a recommendation. If you asked how to program one then that would be on topic but your asking to find specific software that's a different thing. Anyway its unlikely youd get a answer on this forum so you should consider asking somewhere else for your own sake.